# Ubuntu 23.04 get's stuck in a grey screen with mouse curser after login

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, login

My Ubuntu 23.04 install boots normal, but after I log into my user account it gets stuck at an grey screen and does not react to any input anymore. If I boot into recovery mode and select fsck and then boot normal it boots without any problems but when I restart it get's stuck again at the grey screen after login. Can anyone help me I'm not that into Linux and originaly wanted to switch for my laptop but now out of nothing this issue occured and I can't find any fix on google.

I got the issue on my ASUS ZenBook 14X UX5401ZA-KP005W

UPDATE
I reinstalled Ubuntu and as of now the issue did not reoccure

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Can you please add to your question the make/model of your laptop. This will help others in the future with this issue. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. It's desktop custom built pc. Used to work well with Linux and Ubuntu but I haven't used Linux on it in a while (years). Graphic card is older nvidia 970 gtx. I have installed 525 drivers, but this didn't help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/987316/booting-ubuntu-stuck-at-grey-screen

Comment: Yes I've already read that post but my issue was differend because the grey screen appeard after login and I had no turned off displays plugged in.

Comment: @TalaatEtman, It is all about Ubuntu 23 which is not covered by that question.

Comment: I just ran into what sounds like this. I'm on ubuntu 23.10 with Xorg. I wonder if it had anything to do with xbacklight? it seems that when I remove it, after a restart or two the issue doesn't happen, but I'm not sure if that's actually the case.